# Python typing: declare type of callable when give it instance method

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

Consider the following code:

```
import typing

def a(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y

class F(object):
    def b(self, x: int, y: int) -> int:
        return x + y

def call(operation: typing.Callable[[int, int], int]) -> int:
    return operation(2, 2)

call(a)

f = F()
call(f.b)
```

My PyCharm IDE indicates a typing error for the last line:

[image: 1]

Is it a typing/type declaration error? Is the PyCharm type checker failing? If it's a typing error, what should it be?

Comment: I'd report that as a bug to PyCharm. That looks like a bug to me. The bound method has the right signature, the `self` argument is dropped.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: the type of `self` is implied and doesn't need specifying. Even if you did, you'd have to use `self: 'F'` (a string literal), because the class `F` doesn't exist yet when functions are created.

Comment: pycharm error. And @MoinuddinQuadri no, as you can see from the error, it was detected correctly.

Comment: Okay, thank's for replies and bug report.

Comment: This bug still exists CAO this timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a PyCharm typechecker bug. The [mypy typechecker](http://mypy-lang.org) accepts your example without warnings or errors:

```
$ bin/mypy --verbose so_41869174.py
LOG:  Mypy version 0.470
LOG:  Parsing so_41869174.py (so_41869174)
LOG:  Parsing lib/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/3/typing.pyi (typing)
LOG:  Parsing lib/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/3/builtins.pyi (builtins)
LOG:  Parsing lib/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/3/sys.pyi (sys)
LOG:  Parsing lib/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/3/abc.pyi (abc)
LOG:  Parsing lib/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/3/types.pyi (types)
LOG:  Parsing lib/mypy/typeshed/third_party/2and3/mypy_extensions.pyi (mypy_extensions)
LOG:  Parsing lib/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/3/_importlib_modulespec.pyi (_importlib_modulespec)
LOG:  Loaded graph with 8 nodes
LOG:  Found 2 SCCs; largest has 7 nodes
LOG:  Processing SCC of size 7 (_importlib_modulespec mypy_extensions types abc typing sys builtins) as inherently stale
LOG:  Processing SCC singleton (so_41869174) as inherently stale
LOG:  No fresh SCCs left in queue
LOG:  Build finished in 0.482 seconds with 8 modules, 1708 types, and 0 errors
```

Because `F().b` is a *bound method*, it inherits the signature of the underlying function *without the `self` argument* (as it is the job of the bound method to pass in the bound instance).

For example, the [`typing.get_type_hints()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints), applied to the bound method, correctly omits `self`:

```
>>> typing.get_type_hints(f.b)
{'x': <class 'int'>, 'y': <class 'int'>, 'return': <class 'int'>}
```